# Razor view engine for ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, razor, express

I've been toying around with NodeJS, ExpressJS etc, and would really like to be able to have a template engine closer to ASP.Net MVC's Razor engine for node (jshtml).  I'm curious if anyone is familiar with such a beast, or something closer to it.

The main feature I am wanting is region/section based inserts against a master/parent layout/template, which doesn't seem to be a feature in the template engines for node I have seen so far.

---

**-- edit: 2012-02-09 --**

I'm essentially wanting to be able to do the following...

_layout.jshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!-- meta tags, etc -->

  <!-- title set in page -->
  <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>

  <!-- site-wide styles -->

  @RenderSection("Styles", false)
</head>
<body class="@ViewBag.PageClass">
  <!-- site-wide header -->

  <div id="side_content">
    @RenderSection("Side", false)
  </div>

  <div id="main_content">
    @RenderBody()
  </div>

  <!-- site-wide footer -->

  <!-- site-wide scripts -->

  @RenderSection("Scripts", false)
</body>
</html>
```

mypage.jshtml

```
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "My Page";
  ViewBag.PageClass = "page-x";
}

@section Styles {
  <link ... />
}

@section Scripts {
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var pagesettings = @Html.Raw(Model.SomeJsonContentFromController);
  </script>
}

@section Side {
  side content here
}

main content here
```

---

Which is pass certain criteria from the view into the layout including multiple sections.  I haven't seen an example of how to do this in Jade or EJS, if it's possible I would appreciate the insight.

---

*-- edit: 2012-02-13 --*

It looks like ExpressJS 3 + Jade there are now "extends" and "block" keywords for defining precisely what I was looking for.  Example taken [from here](http://www.devthought.com/code/use-jade-blocks-not-layouts/).  Thanks to [@Don](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6845/don) for his answer & comment.

```
// my-template.jade
extends my-layout

// only guessing this var will be passed to the layout (testing later)
- var pageTitle = "My Template";
- var pageClass = "my-template";

block styles
  style(type="text/css")

block scripts
  script(src="myscript.js")

block side
  div Side Content Here

block main
  div Main Content Here
```

```
//my-layout.jade
doctype 5
html
  head
    title #{pageTitle} - My Site
  body(class=pageClass)
    #side
      block side
    #main
      block main
    block scripts
```

I'm not 100% sure about some aspects above (namely variables carrying to the layout from the template... will try to confirm later.

Comment: The feature your asking for is in both jade and dust. Look harder.

Comment: It looks like the view can be used as the body for the parent, not sure how you can plug multiple sections via Jade.  Also, I like the html tags where they are used.. EJS is probably closest to what I want.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[Vash](https://github.com/kirbysayshi/vash) is the most feature complete and up-to-date razor clone I have found yet. Definitely check that one out.

Comment: Winner, winner, chicken dinner... closest I've seen yet.

Comment: Awesome, i now have nodejs + express framework tooling in VS2012, and templating engine i know and love. https://nodejstools.codeplex.com/

Comment: Vash is the only one of the template engines mentioned in an answer that is still maintained. Bliss and JSHTML seem to have been abandoned.

Answer (score 12):

I just came across the [Bliss](https://github.com/cstivers78/bliss/wiki) template engine. It uses almost exact razor syntax. You may have to do some minimal work to integrate it cleanly into express.

[Combining with express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10890958/how-to-configure-bliss-templating-in-express-js)

Comment: The old correct answer mentions bliss, but hadn't fully looked into it.  Editing to add a link to another question/answer on integrating Bliss with express.

Answer (score 7):

I was just going to take a look at Bliss, when I ran into JSHTML which seems to support Express JS.

https://github.com/elmerbulthuis/jshtml

Comment: I had seen this.. the biggest missing item is section support, but it's pretty nice

Answer (score 1):

I haven't come across a node view engine that replicates the Razor syntax, which is rather nice but pretty much unique to .Net.  Might be a good project to start on github.

For partial support, check out partials in EJS or imports in Jade.  It's not a total analog to what you are looking for, but they'll do the job.  My personal opinion, dig into Jade; the more you use it the more you'll love it.

Comment: +1 for now...  Jade looks interesting and a step up from HAML... EJS is probably closest to what I am looking for.  I've thought about starting it as a project, just thinking an existing solution might be a nice place to start if available.

Comment: Just stumbled across this today.  Take a look at how Jade + Express 3 uses Blocks and Extends to make templating even more powerful.. http://www.devthought.com/code/use-jade-blocks-not-layouts/

Comment: ejs doesn't do template inheritance or sections/blocks.

Answer (score 1):

[RAZ: Razor-Express view template engine for NodeJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/raz)

I tried to make its syntax as close as possible to *ASP.NET MVC Razor*.

Adapted for *RAZ* syntax examples from the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9197440/1844247):

*_layout.raz*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>@ViewData.Title</title>
  @Html.section("Styles", false)
</head>
<body class="@ViewData.PageClass">
  <div id="side_content">
    @Html.section("Side", false)
  </div>

  <div id="main_content">
    @Html.body()
  </div>

  @Html.section("Scripts", false)
</body>
</html>
```

*mypage.raz*

```
@{
    Html.layout = "_layout";
    ViewData.Title = "My Page";
    ViewData.PageClass = "page-x";
}

@section Styles {
    <style type="text/css">
        #side_content { background-color: yellow; }
        #main_content { background-color: skyblue; }
    </style>
}

@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var pagesettings = @Html.raw("<div>Raw content example</div>");
    </script>
}

@section Side {
    <div>side content here</div>
}

main content here
```

---

Constructive feedback is welcomed.